# Azure Logout redirect URL as http instead of https

Tags: redirect, azure-ad-b2c, logout

I have developed a desktop application using ElectronJS and React. In here we have used Azure AD B2C for authentication using the **msal.js** npm package. ElectronJS on successful build will run on the file protocol method.

But Azure AD B2C does not support file protocol (file://somepath/some). So the only other option is, while running in production we will create a server locally with some specific port and in that case Redirect URLs for Sign In, Sign up and forgot password we have used the localhost with port number which we will create when the app runs. Example `http://localhost:18090`.

Everything is working fine, except for Logout. But the problem is Logout URLs does not support 'http' URLs, as it throws me a error to enter only https URL.

Is there any other way we can proceed in case of Logout using `http://localhost`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot use `http://localhost` as the logout URL, **The logout URL must start with "HTTPS"**.

[image]

Comment: Ya you are correct. But is there any other way to without Redirecting after logout?

Comment: @Shruthi        If you do not want to be redirected after logout, Just not specify the "post_logout_redirect_uri" parameter, but, as the documentation says,when you want to sign the user out of the application, it isn't enough to clear the application's cookies or otherwise end the session with the user. You must also redirect the user to Azure AD B2C to log out.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect#send-a-sign-out-request

Comment: If I don't specify the "post_logout_redirect_uri" as well it is redirecting to Azure AD B2C but throws mismatch redirect uri error.

Comment: Hi @Shruthi i see the issue have ne acknowledge [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/52160/azure-logout-redirect-url-as-http-instead-of-https.html). does it resolve your issue or still looking for any help on this

Comment: Hi @Shruthi Just wanted to know that are you still looking for any help on this..?